# precedence parenthesis in C++ definitions

Tags: c++, function

Why is the following code illegal in C++?

```
(int) foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

After all, the first parenthesis in

```
int( * foo )();
```

suggests that parenthesis can be used for precedence purposes in declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the parentheses in your second example does not suggest that. It is merely a syntax construct that means "This is a pointer to function". It does not rely on precedence.

The code is illegal because there's no expression starting with a `(` that's valid in the context where you can declare a function (i.e.: The global scope, a class scope or a namespace scope).

Comment: And by syntax construct you mean …

Comment: ... a sequence of tokens defined to have a certain meaning when in a certain context.

Comment: Basically, you are saying that parenthesis are given different meanings according to the context: sometimes they are precedence fixing (e.g. in mathematical expressions), sometimes they indicate function call, and sometimes they are used in pointers to functions. Am I missing any other usage?

Comment: Yes, that's it. For other usages: Other than the ones you mention, I can only remmember the syntax for a cast: the single (that I can remmember, as the standard doesn't exactly have a listing, and looking for all of them on more than 1000 pages is a little hard) way to actually enclose a lone typename around them.